# gfでファイルを開く時に、同名のディレクトリを開かないようにしたい

Tags: vim

pathとincludeを設定して、suffixesaddを設定してincludeexprを設定したのに、拡張子を除いたファイル名と同名のディレクトリがあった場合gfでそちらを開いてしまうのですが、解決策はありますでしょうか？

何か他に設定しなくてはいけない事があるのでしょうか？

以上、宜しくお願いいたします。

Comment: もし github のアカウントをお持ちでしたらこちらに登録願えないでしょうか？ https://github.com/vim-jp/issues/issues

Comment: [vim-jp/issuesのissueへのリンク](https://github.com/vim-jp/issues/issues/679)。そちらで解決していたら、SO上でも (回答を書いて) 解決済みにしていただけるとみんなの役に立つと思います。

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/vim-jp/issues/issues/679

現状の仕様ではデフォルト動作の変更を行う事は難しいと判断しました。
代わりに gf のアクションを map で挿げ替える事で解決する方法を記しました。